# Integrating Magento and Wordpress Users

Tags: magento

I've found posts on letting Wordpress manage Magento users and vise versa, but what I'm looking to do is not to have one manage users over the other. I'd like users to have the option to sign up through the shop or through the Wordpress main site, but enable Wordpress to use the Magento users and vise versa.
Should I install both:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration.html
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are a lot of different solutions for integrating allowing use of [Magento Blocks in  Wordpress](http://www.webdesignlondon-tristar.co.uk/wordpress-plugins/wordgento) or [using Wordpress functions in Magento](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/magento-wordpress-deluxe-extension/), what you are looking for is *single login*.

It can be done via a WP Plugin:

1. **[Mage Enabler](http://mysillypointofview.richardferaro.com/2010/05/11/mage-enabler/).** It's a WP plugin that gives raw access to the Mage object - you can do single login plus access Magento methods within WordPress (pull templates from Magento, display categories, products and checkout from your blog).
2. [**Magento WordPress Integration**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/). I haven't examined this one.

Or via a Magento extension:

1. [**FIshPig's WordPress Customer Synchronisation**](http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-customer-synchronisation.html)
2. [**Single Sign-On For Magento And WordPress**](http://codecanyon.net/item/single-signon-for-magento-and-wordpress/861453)

Comment: @DannyMichel If that was the solution, please mark it as such.

Comment: Oh, I wasnt aware of marking solutions